# Task Parallelism on haskell code

Tags: haskell, parallel-processing, par

I have struggling to understand some aspects of parallelism on haskell. I have to apply parallelism to a piece of code, but the attempts I have tried are not working properly.

The function is this one:

```
fft :: [Complex Float] -> [Complex Float]
fft [a] = [a]
fft as = interleave ls rs
  where
    (cs,ds) = bflyS as
    ls = fft cs
    rs = fft ds

interleave [] bs = bs
interleave (a:as) bs = a : interleave bs as

halve as = splitAt n' as
   where
    n' = div (length as + 1) 2

-- twiddle factors
tw :: Int -> Int -> Complex Float
tw n k = cis (-2 * pi * fromIntegral k / fromIntegral n)

bflyS :: [Complex Float] -> ([Complex Float], [Complex Float])
bflyS as = (los,rts)
  where
    (ls,rs) = halve as
    los = zipWith (+) ls rs
    ros = zipWith (-) ls rs
    rts = zipWith (*) ros [tw n i | i <- [0..n - 1]]
    n = length a
```

My attempts on making this function task parallel are the following ones:

```
bflySTask :: [Complex Float] -> ([Complex Float], [Complex Float])
bflySTask as = (los,rts) `using` if n>1000 then  parTuple2 (parListChunk 500 rseq)    (parListChunk 500 rseq) else r0
  where
    (ls,rs) = halve as
    los = zipWith (+) ls rs 
    ros = zipWith (-) ls rs
    n = length as
    fx =  (map (tw (n)) [0..n-1])
    rts =  zipWith (*) ros fx
```

And with the Par Monad

```
bflySTask :: [Complex Float] -> ([Complex Float], [Complex Float])
bflySTask as = f as
  where
    (ls,rs) = halve as
    los = zipWith (+) ls rs
    ros = zipWith (-) ls rs
    n = length as
    fx = (map (tw (n)) [0..n-1]) 

    f as = if n>10000 then
                runPar $ do
                v1<-new
            v2<-new
            fork $ put v1 (zipWith (*) ros fx)
            fork $ put v2 (zipWith (+) ls rs)
            a <- get v1
            b <- get v2
            return (a, b)
        else
            (zipWith (+) ls rs, zipWith (*) ros fx)
```

Both approaches are getting little parallelism like a Parallel GC work balance of 1.30 and some sparks are been GC'd and fizzled. Does any one know what can I do different to apply parallelism on this functions without changing the data structure ?

Comment: It is to guarantee that the function is the one for a list. I was using an UBV.Vector and list on the same code, that is why they are there. I will edit the code to take them off, since I am not allowed to use UBV.Vector on this code.

Comment: I figured it was something like that, but it's always good to have clarification instead of trying to guess.

Comment: where is `tw` defined in your `bflyS` function?

Comment: I forgot to add it, sorry fot that. I have alredy edited the code to include it.

Comment: There's still stuff missing. I can't find a definition of `halve`. I don't know what kind of data you are applying this to. It also seems as if this is just a step of some recursive divide-and-conquer algorithm. If so, it's important to see that (for example, when using the `Par` monad, you definitely don't want to have one `runPar` call per recursive call, but only one at the top).

Comment: Sorry for that, I have added the remaining parts of the code as well. The function is a radix 2 Cooley-Tukey fast fourier transformation. I will try do do the runPar then on the fft function and see if I can get a better parallelism. However, even with the recursion, do you thing the bflyS function can support a good parallel strategy ?